# Can you USB tether from your computer?

Tags: windows

No, I'm not talking about sharing my phone's hotspot with my computer, I do that on the daily. No, I want to know if it's possible to share my computer's internet connection over USB to another device.

I've got a windows 10 PC and I want to USB tether an Oculus Quest 2 which is an android based device.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=reverse+tether

Comment: There are a lot of duplicates already on this site for this question. Search for 'reverse tether'.

Comment: Why don't you just use Windows 10 built-in Hotspot support?